# How can I add conditionals to the plot command?

Tags: matplotlib, boolean, histogram

Here's part of a function in my code: (using Python)

```
def numsli_expc (L,rang1,rang2,nuni,nshots,succ1 = False):  
...
    hist = plt.bar(spec.keys(), spec.values(), width=np.abs((rang2-rang1)/L), color='deepskyblue',alpha = 0.7)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way I can make `color` in my plot command determined by the argument `succ1`. For example, the default here is `False`. Can I make `color='red'` if `succ1=True`? (I could do that by copying the 'hist' command one more time. However that costs extra time and gives me some color mixing. Is there a simpler method that allows me to only use that once?)

Thanks:)

Comment: `..., color=["blue", "red"][succ1], alpha...`?

Comment: @Mr. T Thanks, that helps:)